# Parsing JSON from PHP by SBJson

Tags: php, objective-c, json, three20, sbjson

Now I'm trying to POST jpeg files to MySQL via PHP and GET from MySQL to iOS.

In GET method I encode jpeg(as NSData) and some related data(ex. caption, timestamp) to JSON  on PHP script using json_encode().

```
    {"caption":"(captiondata)","img":"(imagedata)","timestamp":"(timestampdata)"}
```

Then I set the datas into array like,

```
    [{"caption":"(captiondata)","img":"(imagedata)","timestamp":"(timestampdata)"},
     {"caption":"(captiondata)","img":"(imagedata)","timestamp":"(timestampdata)"},
     .......,
     {"caption":"(captiondata)","img":"(imagedata)","timestamp":"(timestampdata)"}]
```

I believe I can parse and get this JSON by echo (json_encode ()) on PHP and SBJsonParser on iOS but nothing returns to my App. Here's my code in iOS.(Also I use TTURLRequest by Three20)

```
    TTURLRequest* request = [TTURLRequest requestWithURL:url delegate:self];
    request.cachePolicy = cachePolicy;
    TTURLJSONResponse* response = [[[TTURLJSONResponse alloc] init] autorelease];
    request.response = response;
    [request send];

    - (void)requestDidFinishLoad:(TTURLRequest*)request {
        TTURLJSONResponse* response = request.response;
        NSLog(@"%@",response);
    }
```

Comment: If you are targeting for iOS5+ then consider using Apple's own JSON parser. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: @Devraj It seems to be so good. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: What's the output you're getting in the console? try to put a `NSLog(@"didFinishLoad fired");` to tell if the `requestDidFinishLoad` is getting fired or not.

Answer (score 0):

Can you print all the logs in `requestDidFinishLoad:`?

The response is the `rootObject` of `TTURLJSONResponse`.

```
- (void)requestDidFinishLoad:(TTURLRequest*)request {

    TTURLJSONResponse *response = request.response;
    NSDictionary *dict = response.rootObject;
    NSLog(@"dict : %@",dict);

}
```

In your case,

```
- (void)requestDidFinishLoad:(TTURLRequest*)request {
    TTURLJSONResponse* response = request.response;
    NSLog(@"%@",response);
}
```

The response may look like `<TTURLJSONResponse: 0x125398c0>`

If still nothing returns, you may check the `requestDidFinishLoad:` is been called and not the cache issue.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I changed my code and checked but PHP returns only **()**. I set request.cachePolicy = TTURLRequestCachePolicyNone now.